# why base stations have 2 receiving antenna and only one transmitter?

Tags: antenna, communication, wireless, telecommunications

I read that a base station is divided up into sectors to accommodate multiple service providers on a single tower.
why each sector has two receiving antennas and only one transmitting antenna,
As we require more downlink than uplink?

Answer (score 0):

'Of the three antennas, two are for receiving and one is for transmitting. Two are used on the receive side so that the base station can compare signals and select the best antenna for each user within the cell. This is known as 'diversity' reception to more equally manage the power differences between the cellular base station transmitter and the small battery powered cellphone transmitter.'

Reference:

https://ethw.org/Cellular_Base_Stations

Comment: Hi Shashank, Have I answered your question? If I have, could you please accept my answer?